# Killing Server side processing after HttpClient times out

Tags: c#

We use HttpClient to send requests and have a custom time out for different APIs based on our customer needs. However we see that server continues to process requests on different occasions while the client times out? Is there a way to kill server side processing as soon as the client times out?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add some relevant code to the question, so Users can evaluate what a possible solution could be. You might also want to check out [ask] and take the [tour]. Example code does not need to be the exact code from production, best is a [mcve]. It would really help, if we knew what your server implementation looks like. Usually, cancelling requests would be done by using a CancellationToken.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core and if so, are you making use of the CancellationToken for the web requests?

Comment: Yes we are using ASP.Net core and we re using Cancellation token which gets propagated long with SendAsync calls.

Comment: Hi @Sr_11, take a look at my answer. Great that you're using Cancellation on the client side but you can make use of it server side too.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported server-side by making use of the `CancellationToken`.

Take a look at this [article by Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/).  ASP.NET Core will automatically bind any CancellationToken parameters in an action method to the HttpContext.RequestAborted token.

**Client:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Fetching data ...");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);
var result = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:7281/WeatherForecast");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Server:**

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Request {System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.Id}: Fetching weather information");
            await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            var results = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();

            _logger.LogInformation($"Request {System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.Id}: Number of results: {results.Count()}");

            return results;
        }
```

If I drop the timeout to 4 or less seconds, the request completes. With a timeout of 6 seconds, the client aborts the request.  The server "hears" this via the `CancellationToken` and terminates before processing further.

In your case, you would need to pass the `CancellationToken` to whatever back-end fetches you're doing or check if the process has been cancelled.

Comment: After reading through literature and posts on stack overflow, it seems that the task is not immediately cancelled when using cancellation token on server side if it has started. And we will need to do CancellationToken.throwIfCancellationRequested checks on server side before start of task to ensure server side processing doesnt proceed any further.

Comment: Yeah that's normal. Knowing when/should a task be aborted is a business workflow.
Frameworks like MediatR pass the token along with the process and it's up to the consumer to make use of cancellation (such as defining when cancellation can/should occur). If you're using Dapper or Entity Framework, those processes take cancellation into account (like `ToListAsync(CancellationToken)`) so your work is mostly just delivering the token to those methods which is fairly simple.